# Angular and the $watch method within FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a project that makes heavy use of AngularJS and i'm using some of the pre-written code to add more features to the page.

```
link: ($scope, element, attrs)->
    $scope.$watch("model", (newValue, oldValue)->
        if(newValue != oldValue && newValue != "")
            openModal($scope, event)
            refreshShiftList($scope)
    ,false)
```

This is the $watch method that says, if anything changes...do this.  And when you click on an element on the page, it should launch the modal.  (It does this fine on Chrome, and everywhere else.) But on Firefox, it is apparently not grabbing the (event).  - The code worked on all browsers before but I added the event in here, which works on Chrome, not FF so this is the variable that has changed within this code. -  If I add a click to this event, it will work, but that is messy.

```
link: ($scope, element, attrs)->
    $scope.$watch("model", (newValue, oldValue)->
        if(newValue != oldValue && newValue != "")
            FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

            if FIREFOX
                $('.fc-event').click (event) ->
                    openModal($scope, event)
                    refreshShiftList($scope)
            else
                openModal($scope, event)
                refreshShiftList($scope)
    ,false)
```

Plus this approach only works half-way.  It works, but the binding will not be set until after clicking for the first time...I want it available from the get-go.  What am I doing wrong here?  Or what is a good way to make the event detectable on Firefox.

I don't this I can create a fiddle since this is not regular js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code to no longer be in coffee results in this:

```
{
  link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
    return $scope.$watch("model", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue !== "") {
        openModal($scope, event);
        return refreshShiftList($scope);
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
```

I don't see an event variable anywhere and am surprised it's working in chrome at all. What are you expecting the event to be?